Left click moves 3D cursor
Whenever I start blender it has it so that when I left click it moves the 3D cursor, even though I have Select Box selected on the T toolbar.
When I factory reset to default this goes away but I don't want to change to default settings anytime. What is going on?

Could you explain what specifically you mean by "it has it so that when I left click it moves the 3D cursor"? What do you do when you open Blender exactly? What happens?

Under Edit > Preferences > Keymap, type '3d cursor' (without the quotes) into the Name search field. That should show two entries under 3D View, both labelled 'Set 3D Cursor'. The first one should be for 'Shift Right Mouse' with the 'Shift' button selected, and the second for 'Left Mouse' without any buttons selected. Also, do you have any non-Blender addons installed?

Aare you sure you set Blender to left-click-select? That there is how right-click-select works.
